# Using QIODevice with anonymous pipes

Tags: windows, qt, pipe, qiodevice, anonymous-pipes

I want to use a [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) in order to read from a unnamed pipe if data is available.
I tried this with QFile:

```
m_pFile_Pipe = new QFile();
HANDLE hRead, hWrite;
connect(m_pFile_Pipe, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(OutputAvailable_QFile()));

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &sa, 0);
auto fhRead = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hRead, _O_RDONLY);
auto OpenResult = m_pFile_Pipe->open(fhRead, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

The "raw" pipe itself works, I can read data from it.
However, readyRead() is never signaled and during testing:

```
void TestPipe() {
    char acBuffer[128];
    DWORD NumBytesRead;

    auto NumBytes = m_pFile_Pipe->bytesAvailable();
    qDebug() << "NumBytes" << NumBytes;
    ReadFile(hRead, acBuffer, sizeof(acBuffer), &NumBytesRead, NULL);
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(acBuffer);
    while (m_pFile_Pipe->canReadLine()) {
        auto out = m_pFile_Pipe->readLine(512);
        qDebug() << "Line: " << out;
    }
    auto out_all = m_pFile_Pipe->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Raw: " << out_all;
}
```

NumBytes was always 0, canReadLine() always returned false, and readAll() did not return.
ReadFile() could read the expected data.

Is there a [QOIDevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) to use for anonymous pipes?
The Qt docs say that [QLocalSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html) shall be used for named pipes, but I did not find anything about anonymous pipes.

Comment: named and anonymous pipes is absolute the same in windows. anonymous(unnamed) is partial case of named (with empty or random (in old windows versions) name. if `QLocalSocket` can be used with named pipes - it can be used with anonymous of course.

Comment: Well, QLocalSocket takes the name to the pipe, so I do not know how to pass it the unamed one.

Comment: *`QLocalSocket` shall be used for named pipes* - how i understand docs - this is false. the `QLocalSocket` used pipes as internal implementation, but you can not assign external pipe for it. i don know QT simply note that exist only one type of pipes in windows - pipes. which name of pipe (empty it or not) - not affect it functional. so named and anonymous pipes - the same - not different things

Comment: I don't really know about windows pipes, but what is used with Qt to detect events on HANDLEs is [QWinEventNotifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwineventnotifier.html) - you might be able to detect changes by using such a notifier and connecting it to the device

Comment: Also, since we are talking about IO - [QSocketNotifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html#details) may be useful as well